# About hiding echo commands in command prompt

Tags: cmd, echo

I create a batch file like this (The batch file is on the desktop):

```
@echo off
echo bla bla bla
```

When I execute it, the file is shown like this:

```
C:\Users\ÇAĞATAY\Desktop>echo bla bla bla
bla bla bla
```

But, I want to hide all of the first line. I want to like this:

```
bla bla bla
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` suppresses command repetition for this command.

`echo off` suppresses command repetition for all following commands -BUT...

`@echo off` consequently suppresses command repetition for this and all following commands - BUT...

...BUT: this works only in batch files, not on command line.

If you want to suppress command repetition on command line, you have to precede every command with `@`